# If statement works in console, not in source

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, click

I have the following if statement within a click function:

```
$('#rent-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.house-card:not(.sold)').fadeIn('fast');
  $('.for-sale').fadeOut('fast');
  $('.rental').fadeIn('fast');
  $('.sold').fadeOut('fast');
  $('.comm').fadeOut('fast');
  if ( $('.house-card:visible').length == 0 ) {
    $('#no-results').show();
  }
  return false;
});
```

All of the code is wrapped in a doc ready function so that can't be the problem. I am not sure why that when the parameters are set for this if statement to resolve true, it always resolves false. When I click #rent-link and then run the if statement alone in console it resolves true.

Thanks for the help.

Edit:

I updated my code with a settimeout function and it worked. You guys were right, thank you!

Here is the working code:

```
$('#rent-link').on('click', function() {
            $('.house-card:not(.sold)').fadeIn('fast');
            $('.for-sale').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.rental').fadeIn('fast');
            $('.sold').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.comm').fadeOut('fast');
            setTimeout(function() { 
                if ( $('.house-card:visible').length === 0 ) {
                    $('#no-results').show();
                } 
            }, 500); 
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Are you able to replicate the issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Maybe `fadeOut('fast')` is not fast enough, i.e. you're checking before all `.house-cards` have became invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks likely that there are probably still some visible `.house-card` elements when the `if` statement runs.

The `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions are asynchronous, using a series of intervals to fade out the opacity before finally setting the elements to `hidden`. It's likely that the `if` statement is executing before the functions finish and actually hide the elements.

When you click the button then run the statement in the console, you're probably taking longer than the half second the fade functions take before actually running the command, so the elements would have already been hidden before you run the command.

To be sure that the `if` statement is running after the animations are complete, you can use a callback function, as described at http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/ . Something like:

```
$('.sold').fadeOut('fast', function() {
  if ( $('.house-card:visible').length == 0 ) {
    $('#no-results').show();
  }
});
```

Note that this will only be sure that there are no `.house-card.sold:visible` elements. I am not sure if `.comm` and `.for-sale` are also on `.house-card` elements, but if they are, it will probably take a bit more than this to be sure that none of them are visible too.

Comment: Thanks! @jonhopkins i've been staring at this too long and that didn't even cross my mind!

Comment: @Jhauge, I've edited the answer to explain a possible way to get the if statement to run the way you are expecting, but you seem to have beat me to it with the `setTimeout` code :)